# Many to many mapping in SQL Azure Federation using Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework-4, azure-sql-database

In Entity Framework 4.1 and above (using Code First) if we have a many to many mapping between 2 tables then EF creates a mapping table which contains 2 columns (primary key from each of the 2 tables)
e.g. if we have Trips and Activities and we have many to many relationships between the 2, then EF Code First automatically creates a TripActivities table which has 2 columns namely Trip_TripId and Activity_ActivityId.

However if we were to create Trips and Activities tables in SQL Azure Federation, then the TripsActivities table would also need to have the CustomerId column (if we are federating on the CustomerId column). 
So the question is how can we achieve this many to many mapping such that EF inserts the CustomerId value into the TripsActivities table as well in addition to the TripId and ActivityId columns?

Answer (score 0):

I found an article on this site which showed me how to implement this ( http://bit.ly/tmU8f3 ) . 
Essentially we need to create the Entity for the mapping table as well in the Code.
Here is an example of the same:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1.EF
{
[Table("Emp", Schema="Common")]
public class Emp
{
    public Emp()
    {
        //Projects = new HashSet<Project>();
        ProjectEmps = new HashSet<ProjectEmps>();
    }

    public virtual Guid EmpId { get; set; }
    public virtual string EmpName { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectEmps> ProjectEmps { get; set; }

}

[Table("Project", Schema="Common")]
public class Project
{
    public Project()
    {
        //Emps = new HashSet<Emp>();
        ProjectEmps = new HashSet<ProjectEmps>();
    }

    public virtual Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProjectName { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<Emp> Emps { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectEmps> ProjectEmps { get; set; }
}

[Table("ProjectEmps", Schema = "Common")]
public class ProjectEmps
{
    public Emp Emp { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public Guid Emp_EmpId { get; set; }
    public Guid Project_ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
}

public class EmpContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Emp> Emps { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProjectEmps> ProjectEmps { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EmpConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProjectConfiguration());

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectEmps>().HasKey(p => new {p.Project_ProjectId, p.Emp_EmpId})
            .HasRequired(p => p.Emp).WithMany(p => p.ProjectEmps).HasForeignKey(p => p.Emp_EmpId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectEmps>().HasRequired(p => p.Project).WithMany(p => p.ProjectEmps).HasForeignKey(p => p.Project_ProjectId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectEmps>().ToTable("ProjectEmps", "Common");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}

public class EmpConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Emp>
{
    public EmpConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Common.Emp");

        this.HasMany(i => i.ProjectEmps).WithRequired(e => e.Emp);
    }
}

public class ProjectConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Project>
{
    public ProjectConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Project","Common");

        this.HasMany(i => i.ProjectEmps)
            .WithRequired(p => p.Project);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Database.SetInitializer<EmpContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EmpContext>());

      var p1 = new Project() { ProjectId = Guid.NewGuid(), ProjectName = "Fun Boat" };
      var p2 = new Project() { ProjectId = Guid.NewGuid(), ProjectName = "Jumbo Jet" };
      var p3 = new Project() { ProjectId = Guid.NewGuid(), ProjectName = "Free Zoo" };

        var e1 = new Emp() { EmpId = Guid.NewGuid(), EmpName = "Wriju" };
        var e2 = new Emp() { EmpId = Guid.NewGuid(), EmpName = "Wrishika" };
        var e3 = new Emp() { EmpId = Guid.NewGuid(), EmpName = "Saswati" };


        var pe1 = new ProjectEmps()
                      {
                          CustomerId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                          Emp = e1,
                          Project = p1,
                          Emp_EmpId = e1.EmpId,
                          Project_ProjectId = p1.ProjectId
                      };

        var pe2 = new ProjectEmps()
        {
            CustomerId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Emp = e2,
            Project = p2,
            Emp_EmpId = e2.EmpId,
            Project_ProjectId = p2.ProjectId
        };

        var pe3 = new ProjectEmps()
        {
            CustomerId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Emp = e3,
            Project = p3,
            Emp_EmpId = e3.EmpId,
            Project_ProjectId = p3.ProjectId
        };

        p1.ProjectEmps.Add(pe1);
        p2.ProjectEmps.Add(pe2);
        p3.ProjectEmps.Add(pe3);

        using (var ctx = new EmpContext())
        {
            ctx.Projects.Add(p1);
            ctx.Projects.Add(p2);
            ctx.Projects.Add(p3);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
           }
       }
     }
```

### }

Answer (score 0):

Not using EF but rather NHibernate, I found the easiest way was to just create a trigger that populates the Federation id value.